# useContext Provider in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm developing a project where I have a `Context`, and I got this error when trying to use the `Provider`:

```
Type '{ children: Element[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ReactNode'.
  Type '{ children: Element[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, type, props
```

**Mainpage.tsx**

```
import { Form } from "../../components/Form";
import { Greet } from "../../components/Greet";

import { UserProvider } from "../../context/UserContext";

const Mainpage: React.FC = () => {

    return(
        <div>
            <UserProvider> // **ERROR HERE !!!**
                <>
                <Greet />
                <Form />
                </>
            </UserProvider>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Mainpage;
```

**UserContext.tsx**

```
import React, { Component, createContext, ReactChild, ReactNode, useState } from "react";

type ContextType={
    name?:string,
    email?:string,
    submit?: (param?:any, param2?:any)=> void
}

export const UserContext = createContext<ContextType | null> (null);

export const UserProvider: React.FC<React.ReactNode> = (children) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

    const onSubmit = (name:string, email:string ) => {

        console.log('Submit App: ' + name, email)
        setName(name)
        setEmail(email)
    }

    return(
        <UserContext.Provider value={{name, email, submit: onSubmit}}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UserProvider is defined as a React component and accept just one children
`UserProvider: React.FC<React.ReactNode>`

You can wrap `<Greet />` and `<Form/>` inside a fragment

```
<>
  <Greet/>
  <Form/>
</>
```

```
....
const Mainpage: React.FC = () => {

    return(
        <div>
            <UserProvider> // **ERROR HERE !!!**
              <>
                <Greet/>
                <Form/>
              </>
            </UserProvider>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Mainpage;
```

---

**UPDATE**:

the problem is here

```
....
export const UserProvider: React.FC = (children) => { // << look at children
....
```

`children` is a prop and shoud be destructured `({ children })` or used from `props.children` in your case `children.children`

```
...
export const UserProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
...
```

Comment: The error remains

Comment: The error talks about a ReactPortal did you use it  somewhere ?

Comment: No, my project actually has only those components. All my code is in my question.

Comment: It's true, it doesn't works https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-chaum-k413v8?file=/src/Mainpage.tsx

Comment: I update my answer, this shoud works

Comment: New error: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'ReactNode'.

Comment: Just use this UserProvider: React.FC instead of UserProvider: React.FC<React.ReactNode>. Children is already defined in React.FC

Comment: New error: Property 'children' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: For some reason, this fixed it: Changing to only UserProvider, whitout any type, and props as {children}:any. But I guess this is not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

By explicitly setting `React.ReactNode` as your component props you are saying that there will only be one node as a child and currently you've got 2 nodes as children.

Change this:

```
export const UserProvider: React.FC<React.ReactNode> = () => {...}
```

To this:

```
export const UserProvider: React.FC = () => {...}
```

An alternative option is to wrap the `children` in a React Fragment like this:

```
<UserProvider> // **ERROR HERE !!!**
  <>
    <Greet />
    <Form />
  </>
</UserProvider>
```

Comment: The error remains